# What is the Big-O Notation for this code?

Tags: c++, algorithm, big-o

I am having trouble deciding between N^2 and NlogN as the Big O? Whats throwing me off is the third nested for loop from k <=j. How do I reconcile this?

```
int Max_Subsequence_Sum( const int A[], const int N )
{
  int This_Sum = 0, Max_Sum = 0;
  for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
  {
    for (int j=i; j<N; j++)
    {
      This_Sum = 0;
      for (int k=i; k<=j; k++)
      {
        This_Sum += A[k];
      }
      if (This_Sum > Max_Sum)
      {
        Max_Sum = This_Sum;
      }
    }
  }
  return Max_Sum;
}
```

Comment: Can you show your effort? I think at least you have made *some* analysis?

Comment: Well the first 2 for loops make me think it would be N^2 because they each time N runs it runs through N once. The third one makes me thing it could be N log N because it continually gets smaller. My measured run times show that this is at least  equal to or greater than N^2 though.

Comment: Why would adding a third loop lower the runtime from N^2?

Comment: probably O(N^3)... this is a really inefficient way to do maximum subsequence sum.

Comment: Well I guess it wouldn't lower the run time so it couldn't be N log N. My only problem with this is that the third loop doesn't run N times so I do not think it would be O(N^3).

Comment: On the efficiency side of things the assignment I got has us analyzing three different given algorithms. This one is the most inefficient. The other two are Nand N Log N

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us analyze the most inner loop first:

```
for (int k=i; k <= j; k++) {
    This_Sum += A[k];
}
```

Here the counter `k` iterates from `i` (inclusive) to `j` (inclusive), this thus means that the body of the `for` loop is performed `j-i+1` times. If we assume that fetching the `k`-th number from an array is done in constant time, and the arithmetic operations (incrementing `k`, calculating the sum of `This_Sum` and `A[k]`, and comparking `k` with `j`), then this thus runs in *O(j-i)*.

The initialization of `This_Sum` and the `if` statement is not significant:

```
This_Sum = 0;
// ...
if (This_Sum > Max_Sum) {
    Max_Sum = This_Sum;
}
```

indeed, if we can compare two numbers in constant time, and set one variable to the value hold by another value in constant time, then regardless whether the condition holds or not, the number of operations is fixed.

Now we can take a look at the loop in the middle, and abstract away the most inner loop:

```
for (int j=i; j < N; j++) {
    // constant number of oprations
    // j-i+1 operations
    // constant number of operations
}
```

Here `j` ranges from `i` to `N`, so that means that the total number of operations is:

```
 N
---
\
/     j - i + 1
---
j=i
```

This sum is equivalent to:

```
                   N
                  ---
                  \
(N-j) * (1 - i) + /   j
                  ---
                  j=i
```

This is an [*arithmetic sum* [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression#Sum) and it is equivalent to:

```
(N - i + 1) × ((1 - i) + (i+N) / 2) = (N - i + 1) × ((N-i) / 2 + 1)
```

or when we expand this:

```
i2/2 + 3×N/2 - 3×i/2 + N2/2 - N×i + 1
```

So that means that we can now focus on the outer loop:

```
for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
    // i2/2 + 3×N/2 - 3×i/2 + N2/2 - N×i + 1
}
```

So now we can again calculate the number of operations with:

```
 N
---
\
/  i2/2 + 3×N/2 - 3×i/2 + N2/2 - N×i + 1
---
i=0
```

We can use [Faulhaber's formula [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula) here to solve this sum, and obtain:

```
(N+1)×(N2+5×N+6)/6
```

or in expanded form:

```
N3/6 + N2 + 11×N/6 + 1
```

which is thus an *O(n<sup>3</sup>)* algorithm.

Comment: I am pretty sure that this is the right answer because my speed for my array of size of 256 was .006 seconds. For 512 it was .048. Using O(N^3) we can do, (512^3)/(256^3) = 8. That means it should take 8 times longer for the 512 data set to run. It just so happens that the 512 data set took .048 seconds. It also just so happens that .006 * 8 = .048. Thank you guys for the help

Comment: @JohnSelnekovic Actual runtime can be very different from complexity since constant multipliers are ignored when computing the complexity.

Answer (score 4):

This can be done with estimation or analysis.  Looking at the inner most loop there are `j-i` operations inside the second loop.  To get the total number of operations one would sum to get :

```
(1+N)(2 N + N^2) / 6
```

Making the algorithm O(N^3).  To estimate one can see that there are three loops which at some point have O(N) calls thus it's O(N^3).